# How to pass data to a slot in vue2.6

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here is the hierarchy. Component A is the parent of Component B. Component B is the parent of Component C.

Component A looks like this:

```
<template>
  <component-b>
    <component-c>
  </component-b>
</template>
```

Component B:

```
<template>
  <input type=text/>
  <slot>
  </slot>
</template>
```

I need component B to pass data from it's context into component C. I am not sure how to do this with slots. Component B has an input box and as the user types I need that data to be bound to the slot, which in turn will cause component C to take that variable and use it within itself.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at scoped slots ~ https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots

For example, in ComponentB...

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="textValue" />
    <slot :text="textValue"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here, I've bound ComponentB's `textValue` data property to a slot-scoped property named `text`.

In ComponentA, you can access this via the `v-slot` directive

```html
<component-b v-slot="{ text }">
  <component-c :some-prop="text" />
</component-b>
```

Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/uj05gqtm/

Comment: very well explained. Thank you for that. Works really well

Comment: Really nice explanation. Saved me some good hours!

Answer (score 0):

You can emit the value from the child.

component A

```
<template>
  <component-b @inputChange="useValue">
    <component-c :data="valueEmited">
  </component-b>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      valueEmited: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    useValue(value) {
      console.log('this is the data emited from the child', value);
      this.valueEmited = value;
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

component b

```
<template>
  <input type=text v-model="text" @change="emitThisValue"/>
  <slot>
  </slot>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    emitThisValue() {
      this.$emit('inputChange', this.text);
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

You can then pass the value to component C as a prop

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event

Comment: very interesting approach